# Count total data with time interval in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, interval

I have an issue that I want to count total data with 1 hour interval. However start time is 7:30

```
Time                   Status
2022-03-24 07:36:00,   Fail
2022-03-24 07:59:00,   Pass
2022-03-24 09:32:00,   Pass
2022-03-24 09:41:00,   Pass
2022-03-24 10:02:00,   Fail
2022-03-24 11:02:00,   Pass
2022-03-24 11:22:00,   Fail
```

You can see that before 8:30 I have 2 data that 1 pass(07:59) and 1 fail(07:36) so I can count it and create data below

```
Time                Status  Total
2022-03-24 08:30    Pass    1
2022-03-24 08:30    Fail    1
2022-03-24 09:30    Pass    0
2022-03-24 09:30    Fail    0
2022-03-24 10:30    Pass    2
2022-03-24 10:30    Fail    1
2022-03-24 11:30    Pass    1
2022-03-24 11:30    Fail    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want group your datapoints with [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN), which allows you to specify an `origin` time and a `stride` interval to use as an offset.

```
SELECT
date_bin('1 hour', Time, TIMESTAMP '2022-03-24 07:30:00') as Time,
Status,
count(*) as Total
FROM datapoints
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when I change your timestamp to '2022-03-24 10:30:00' sql query has the same data with '2022-03-24 07:30:00'

Comment: Do you only want datapoints after that timestamp?

Comment: Yes, even I can do it with Where clause, but it will be better if change timestamp in date_bin make query clear

Comment: After doing some example with date_bin, maybe I understand the purpose of timestamp xD thank you so much for helping me xD